# Permission denied while running a script file (.sh) with a docker file

Tags: linux, docker, shell, dockerfile, file-permissions

What I'm trying to do is,
I created a docker file using Ubuntu as the base image,

```
ARG VERSION
FROM ubuntu:18.04

COPY configs/base.properties /root/base.properties
```

this property file contains some configs and the Dockerfile just copies that into the container. (let's assume I tag this image as `configimage:1.0`)

And then I created a second docker file which uses the above docker image as the base image. (let's assume I tag this as `midbase:1.0`)

```
FROM configimage:1.0

COPY resource/bootstrap.sh .

RUN ["chmod", "a+x", "bootstrap.sh"]

CMD ["ls"]
```

all the script file does is copying the configs I copied in the previous image to a separate location in the container.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p ~/configs

cp --archive ~/root/base.properties ~/configs/base.properties

echo "Configs copied"
```

I added the `ls` command to check that the folder is created in the container (In `midbase:1.0`), but I noticed that the `configs` folder is not created in the `midbase:1.0` container.

Do you have any tips to solve this issue?

Comment: `~/root/base.properties` is not necessarily the same path as `/root/base.properties`. Is this intentional? --- In general, I would recommend to not use paths like `~/something`, but either work with absolute paths or set the `WORKDIR` and work with relative paths.

Comment: ahaa!! Thanks for the input. I'll try that. :)

Comment: soo... did it help?

Comment: You are not running `bootstrap.sh` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
RUN ["sh", "bootstrap.sh"]
```

Comment: HI Akash

I did try this, 
change it to RUN ["sh", "bootstrap.sh"]
then build it again - docker build -t midbase:1.2 .
Then run it - docker run midbase:1.2 

But it only gave this output || 
bin   bootstrap.sh  etc   lib    media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr
boot  dev           home  lib64  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var

|| No configs folder created :/

Comment: do you see the "Configs copied" message after the shell script run ?

Comment: No, I don't see that  as well. :/

Comment: `ls` appears to show content of `/`, is that were you expected the `configs` directory?

Comment: aa yeah! :)  @sborsky